# C++ Is there any threadsafe to write into (faster than not thread safe analogs busted with locks) component?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

So I tried some components (maps, sets, vectors, arrays, queues U name it), I always have to make tham thread safe... and that makes tham slow... Is there any threadsafe to write into component? in Boost or anywhere?

Comment: If you want general thread safety, then I believe none of the Boost containers offer that and you'll essentially have to serialize access to the entire container. If you don't modify the container, concurrent access at different elements should be OK, though.

Comment: Keep in mind that C++ itself is *not* thread-safe and has no concept of threads. It's up to the implementation to provide threading APIs (and almost all do, of course.) If you're using a particular platform, we may be able to recommend platform-specific optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

You can find some in Intel's Thread Building Blocks. You can also find some in Microsoft's PPL.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at **[`libcds`: Concurrent Data Structures](http://libcds.sourceforge.net)** by Max Khiszinsky.

It contains highly generic/configurable lock-free containers and algorithms. It comes with extensive tests. The documentation is about average, I'd say.

> <sup>**Trivia** *The library looked ready for proposition into boost, but (AFAICT) it hinges on the patent-encumberd algorithms that it might contain*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

[Boost.Lockfree](http://tim.klingt.org/boost_lockfree/) was recently under review for inclusion in Boost. I do not know the outcome of this review.